# Why Does :: Only Work With Lists?

Tags: list, scala, collections, cons

What is the reasoning behind making `::` specific to `List` and not available to all subclasses of `Seq`? To give a concrete example:

```
// :: for pattern matching
def getTail[E](s: Seq[E]): Seq[E] = s match {
   case head :: tail => tail
   case empty => empty
}
getTail(Seq(1, 2)) // returns List(2) as expected
getTail(Seq()) // returns List() as expected
getTail(Queue(1, 2)) // returns Queue(1, 2), not Queue(2)
getTail(Buffer(1, 2)) // returns ArrayBuffer(1, 2), not ArrayBuffer(2)

// :: for building sequences
1 :: 2 :: 3:: Nil // Creates List(1, 2, 3)
1 :: 2 :: List(3) // same as above
1 :: 2 :: Queue(3) // does not compile. :: is not a method within Queue
```

All sequences are ordered and have a notion of "head" and "tail," so why did the implementors of the collections library only provide `::` to `List`? Why must I use `+:` if I want to be able to work with all `Seq`?

**Edit:** I understand the performance argument - I've been given it nearly every time I've asked this question - but I largely disagree with it. Imagine a different collection library where only one thing has been changed: the removal of `::` from `List`. What would change?

- I can still build my lists in a performant way using `+:` and `Nil` such as `"A" +: "B" +: Nil`.
- I can still elegantly pattern match using `+:` to extract different parts of my list. e.g. `case head +: tail => println(head)`
- There is a unified method for building and pattern matching all subclasses of `Seq`. This removes the need for a linter to find subtle bugs like the one I've introduced in `getTail`.

I honestly do not see how a method unique to `List` makes anything easier, clearer, or more performant than using `+:`. And if that is the case, then I see no reason for `::` to be specific to `List`. Given this, I don't see the reason for `::` to exist at all.

Comment: it's confusing enough that they need lint rules to guard against it. But not every seq has an efficient tail (if allocations are required).

Comment: I think it's there so the :: unapply / extractor can be efficient. That would mean ::  (as cons) is there just for symmetry.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul It is trivial to make the `::` case class work with all `Seq` instead of just `List`. The extractor would still be efficient for `List`, would it not?

Answer (score 3):

The same reasoning as behind all class-specific operators. Like `#::` for `Stream` or `!` for `Actor`.

As `List` is single-linked, prepending elements and deconstruction into head + tail is performed in O(1). It's basically the most used operation for Lists. The whole idea of List is built around this operation.

Please note, that `List` supports `Seq`'s `+:` as well. But using `::` clearly shows your intentions to use `List` in efficient manner.

Comment: I've responded to this by editing my question. I don't believe performance is a valid reason for having `::`, as `+:` serves an identical purpose, is just as performant, and is usable by all subclasses of `Seq`.